# compose jekyll categories by url page

Tags: jekyll

I'm looking for how to compose jekyll page by categories.

Many example what I found on blog is just about 'category page'.

I don't want just listing category page.

like this

---

- Design (category 1)

  - what is UX/UI (post)
  - Visual design (post)
- Tech (category 2)

  - about Smart Car (post)
  - Smart phone (post)
- Food (category 3)

  - Japan food susi (post)
  - Chinese (post)

---

I want to make header menu by categories and each page. like this

[image]
It is possible to make category url by page?
Or please introduce sample page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can display each category's posts on their ownpage by taking the last level of the url as the current category, then filter posts with it, for example: suppose we have the url `https://marcanuy.github.io/jekyll-skeleton/en/subcategory1/` then we can get `subcategory1` with:

```
{% assign current_cat = page.dir | split: "/" | last%}
```

Then having the current category, we choose the posts that belong to this category:

```
{% assign posts = site.categories[current_cat] | where: 'lang',page.lang %}
```

Finally, we display posts. Here is the full example:

```
{% assign current_cat = page.dir | split: "/" | last%}
{% assign posts = site.categories[current_cat] | where: 'lang',page.lang %}
<ul>
{% for item in posts %}
<li><a href="{{item.url | absolute_url}}">{{item.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can see this working in this [jekyll-skeleton](https://marcanuy.github.io/jekyll-skeleton/) example site, and its source code: https://github.com/marcanuy/jekyll-skeleton